# Unix Shell and colours

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, escape-characters

I need to understand this code snippet that I found in .profile file

```
echo -en "\e[32;44m $(hostname) \e[m";echo -e "\e[m"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This snippet is used to print out the hostname of the system with a blue background and a green font.

To color your shell, you use special color escape sequences.

`\e[` starts the color scheme, `32;` will set the foreground color to green, `44` will set the background color to blue and `m` will end it.

`$(command)` creates a new shell, executes command and returns the result (not the return value).

`hostname` returns the hostname of the current system.

`\e[m` will reset the coloring of the output.

From the echo manpage:

> ```
>    -n     do not output the trailing newline
>    -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

IMHO your snippet could be simplified to
`echo -e "\e[32;44m $(hostname) \e[m";`

See the chapter [6.1 Colours of the BASH Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Sequence_Introducer for more more details